# Jboss windows service does not launch executable from deployed war file

Tags: java, windows, jboss

I have Jboss 4.2.3 installed and Windows Service,Log on AS is set to Local System for that service. When I deploying a small war project which is suppose to launch `notepad.exe`, jboss server runs the command but does not launch `notepad.exe`

When I run the JBoss 4.2.3 from command line with command `run.bat -b 0.0.0.0` it launches `notepad.exe` from war project file Also when I change Log on AS for windows service to Current Windows User from which I am currently logged in and restart Jboss service it launches `notepad.exe`

I want to run Jboss service as Local System and have war file execute the exe, Can any one let me know how can I do that ?